# MATLAB sqlwrite array datatype into PostgreSQL cell

Tags: arrays, database, postgresql, matlab

I'm using [sqlwrite](https://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/database.postgre.connection.sqlwrite.html) to try and write a Table into a PostgreSQL database. From my understanding Postgres supports the [Array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/arrays.html) type.

The table I'm inserting has two columns `x` and `y` where the entries of column `x` are themselves 1xN arrays.

```
T = struct;
T.x = [[1 2 3 4 5 6 8 8 9 10]];
T.y = "test_string";

T = struct2table(T);

sqlwrite(conn, 'my_table', matlabTable);
```

T looks like this

```
T =

  1x2 table

          x                y      
    _____________    _____________

    [1x10 double]    "test_string"
```

This is the error I get when I try running the code

```
Error using database.postgre.connection/sqlwrite>checkDataTypes (line 315)
x column value must be a numeric array or cell array of numeric scalars.

Error in database.postgre.connection/sqlwrite (line 155)
data = checkDataTypes(typNames,typeCategories,data);
```

Is this a limitation of MATLAB's `sqlwrite` or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of Matlab's `sqlwrite` and related functions. They only work on basic data types. That's normal for Matlab's Database Toolbox.

If you want this to work, you'll probably need to convert that value into a SQL string literal that Postgres can convert to an Array, or just replace the Database Toolbox entirely with something that supports Arrays and other advanced SQL types. Here's some code to get you started: https://github.com/janklab/janklab-core/tree/master/Mcode/classes/%2Bjl/%2Bsql